# Insert different values in array in MySQL in the same columns with just 1 insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, sql-insert

How can I do this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO blah (foo, bar) VALUES (".$array[$i].", 1)");
}
```

With just one `INSERT`?

Is it possible?

---

PS: I know `mysql_query` is deprecated.

Comment: `INSERT INTO blah(foo, bar) VALUES (...), (...), (...), (...), ...`

Comment: If `$number` is not a known constant, it is impossible to do this without looping at some stage.

Comment: either you loop and run the query multiple times, or you loop to build up an extended-syntax insert query and then call it once. either way, you're looping. what you want is not possible WITHOUT loops.

Comment: @lad2025 Create an answer for me to accept. Thanks.

Comment: I'll update the question. My intent is not to make multiple Inserts. I want to use just 1 Insert.

Comment: Asked another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954880/wich-way-to-insert-multiple-values-in-array-is-the-most-efficient about the performance. Feel free to answer =DD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass multiple `VALUES` in `INSERT` statement like:

```
INSERT INTO blah(foo, bar) 
VALUES (...), (...), (...), (...),...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$stmt = "";

for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) {
    $stmt .= "INSERT INTO blah (foo, bar) VALUES (" . $array[$i] . ", 1);";
}

//deprecated: mysql_multi_query($stmt);
mysqli_multi_query($stmt);
```

Comment: This way I'll still make multiple Inserts.